# StreamWriter Writing NUL characters at the end of the file when system shutdown abruptly

Tags: c#, streamwriter, shutdown

I am writing some test application to write some text into a text file using `StreamWriter`. While executing the `WriteLine` method the system shuts down abruptly. After rebooting the machine I have observed that there are many NUL characters at the end of the file.

I have searched many sites including MSDN and haven't found a solution to this problem.

Could any one help me to resolve this problem?

This can be easily reproduced if we do the following steps:

1. Create WindowsApplication and place a button control on it.
2. In the button click event handler write the following code:

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

   ```
    {
        string str = "Welcome to the C Sharp programming world with a test application using IO operations.";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, true, Encoding.Unicode, str.Length);
        sw.WriteLine(str);
        sw.Close();        
    }
   ```
3. Run the application and click on the button continuously (Do not stop until machine shutdown) and press the Poweroff button of the PC.
4. Reboot the PC and check the file. It contains the following text:

Welcome to the C Sharp programming world with a test application using IO operations.

Welcome to the C Sharp programming world with a test application using IO operations.

Welcome to the C Sharp programming world with a test application using IO operations.

Welcome to the C Sharp programming world with a test application using IO operations.

Welcome to the C Sharp programming world with a test application using IO operations.

Welcome to the C Sharp programming world with a test application using IO operations.

NULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNUL

The NUL characters will appear in Notepaad++ and we cannot see these characters in normal Notepad.

Comment: Not sure how much of a help it would be, but doing a sw.Flush() before the close, might help  maybe. A UPS would be better though. :(

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with *netcore* on linux (on a raspberry). It look like their is some sort of buffer that are not flushed in time. (`StreamWriter.Flush()` method doesn't help).

The workaround is to set the buffer size to the data size `array.Length` and disable all caching with `FileOptions.WriteThrough` (from msdn:)

> Indicates that the system should write through any intermediate cache
> and go directly to disk.

```
string str = "Welcome to the C Sharp programming world with a test application using IO operations.";
byte[] data = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(str);
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write,
                                FileShare.Read, data.Length, FileOptions.WriteThrough))
{                    
    fs.Write(data , 0, data.Length);
}
```

For those coming from C/C++ it set the posix flag:

> O_DIRECT Try to minimize cache effects of the I/O to and from this
> file. In general this will degrade performance, but it is useful in
> special situations, such as when applications do their own caching.
> File I/O is done directly to/from user space buffers.

More informations: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971746/posix-o-direct-vs-windows-file-flag-write-through-file-flag-no-buffering/15971822)

Comment: I'd be surprised if `WriteThrough` really fixed this. It might reduce the chance but I don't think it makes the write atomic. First, the file size is increased and then the data is written. `WriteThrough` causes a flush after that sequence, I presume.

Answer (score 3):

That happens. When you append a file first its size is corrected in the directory (and that's transactional in NTFS) and then the actual new data is written. There's good chance that if you shut down the system you end up with a file appended with lots of null bytes because data writes are not transactional unlike metadata (file size) writes.

There's no absolute solution to this problem.

Comment: I know it's an old post but i found a solution. The buffer size can be set and caches can be disabled so it go directly to disk at the good size.

Answer (score 0):

I know it looks gross but this is what I had to do to solve the problem. Just put the following code after you have written the string to your file.

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(workingFile.FullName);

//Strip the "null line" from file
if (lines[lines.Length - 1].StartsWith("\0\0\0\0\0"))
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(workingFile.FullName, lines.Take(lines.Length - 1).ToArray());
}
```

What this does is reads all the lines in the file into an Array, if the last line is that pesky NUL line the code will write all elements of the Array minus the last element(NUL line)