# POSIX O_DIRECT vs Windows FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH & FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING

Tags: file, winapi, posix, device

From what I can gather, then using POSIX `O_DIRECT` with `open()` on blocking device files works just the same way as combining both `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` and `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` with `CreateFile()` on Windows - is this correctly assumed by me?

Open:

> **O_DIRECT** Try to minimize cache effects of the I/O to and from this file. In general this will degrade performance, but it is useful in
>   special situations, such as when applications do their own caching.
>   File I/O is done directly to/from user space buffers.

Createfile:

> If **FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH** is used but **FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING**
>   is not also specified, so that system caching is in effect, then the
>   data is written to the system cache but is flushed to disk without
>   delay. If **FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH** and **FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING**
>   are both specified, so that system caching is not in effect, then the
>   data is immediately flushed to disk without going through the Windows
>   system cache. The operating system also requests a write-through of
>   the hard disk's local hardware cache to persistent media.

Comment: I am not sure but with O_DIRECT you may also need O_SYNC to guarantee that data is written to disk. It seems O_DIRECT is skipping page cache and corresponds to FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING. O_SYNC submits data to disk without delay and corresponds to FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH. Please let me know about your opinion.

Comment: @OrcunC I use POSIX AIO, where you can wait for asynchronuous I/O completion with `aio_error()` and `aio_return()`, otherwise I think you can use `fsync()`. I think `O_SYNC` combined with `O_DIRECT` is useful if you want to guarantee the _order_ of I/O completion.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you are looking to do this in Node.js and need aligned buffers etc. you can use https://github.com/ronomon/direct-io

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will have a very similar effect to use those two flags in a Windows system as `O_DIRECT` on a POSIX system. Since these are two different OS's, you can expect that there is no EXACT match.

However, unless you are trying to understand exactly how the filesystem does things, you get "*don't buffer the data, and write it straight to disk as soon as possible*" from both of those options.