# What is the meaning of the posix_memalign in this program?

Tags: c, memory, posix

I have read a program that employs DIRECT_IO in order to insert ONE register (prof struct). My doubt is if I am doing the correct utilization of the posix_memalign here. I know that the allocated memory block must be aligned in order to use the DIRECT_IO approach.

My program is (which is working, but please, let me know any suggestions):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE /* for O_DIRECT */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>  /* required by open() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* open(), write() */
#include <fcntl.h>      /* open() and fcntl() */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define PAGE_SIZE 4096
#define LENGTH  50

typedef struct {
    int nusp;
    char first_name[LENGTH];
    char last_name[LENGTH];
    char department[LENGTH];
    int year_of_begin;
} prof;

int disk_open() {
    int flag;
    int ret;

    flag = O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_DIRECT;

    if ((ret = open("test.header", flag, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) < 0) {
        printf("was impossible to create the file");
        return -1;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    int cmd;
    prof d;
    int arq;
    uint8_t *buf, *loc;
    size_t bufsize;

    do {
        printf("Digite:\n");
        printf("****\n(1) insert\n(2) see register\n(3) leave\n****\n");
        scanf("%d", &cmd);
        switch (cmd) {
            case 1:
                printf("ID: ");
                scanf("%d", &(d.nusp));

                printf("NAME: ");
                scanf("%s", (d.first_name));

                printf("LASTNAME: ");
                scanf("%s", (d.last_name));

                printf("DEPARTAMENT: ");
                scanf("%s", (d.department));

                printf("YEAR: ");
                scanf("%d", &(d.year_of_begin));

                bufsize = sizeof (int) +
                        sizeof (d.first_name) +
                        sizeof (d.last_name) +
                        sizeof (d.department) +
                        sizeof (int);
                printf("bufsize = %d\n", bufsize);
                //buf = (uint8_t*) malloc(bufsize);
                if(posix_memalign((void**)&buf, PAGE_SIZE, bufsize)) {
                    printf("allocation failed\n");
                }

                loc = buf;

                memcpy(loc, &(d.nusp), sizeof (int));
                loc += sizeof (int);

                memcpy(loc, d.first_name, sizeof (d.first_name));
                loc += sizeof (d.first_name);

                memcpy(loc, d.last_name, sizeof (d.first_name));
                loc += sizeof (d.last_name);

                memcpy(loc, d.department, sizeof (d.department));
                loc += sizeof (d.department);

                memcpy(loc, &(d.year_of_begin), sizeof (int));
                loc += sizeof (int);

                arq = disk_open();
                printf("bytes written: %d\n", write(arq, buf, PAGE_SIZE));

                free(buf);

                close(arq);
                break;

            case 2:
                arq = disk_open();

                bufsize = sizeof (int) +
                        sizeof (d.first_name) +
                        sizeof (d.last_name) +
                        sizeof (d.department) +
                        sizeof (int);
                //buf = (uint8_t*) malloc(bufsize);
                 posix_memalign((void**)&buf, PAGE_SIZE, bufsize);

                printf("read %d bytes\n", read(arq, buf, PAGE_SIZE));

                memcpy(&(d.nusp), buf, sizeof (int));
                buf += sizeof (int);

                memcpy(d.first_name, buf, sizeof (d.first_name));
                buf += sizeof (d.first_name);

                memcpy(d.last_name, buf, sizeof (d.last_name));
                buf += sizeof (d.last_name);

                memcpy(d.department, buf, sizeof (d.department));
                buf += sizeof (d.department);

                memcpy(&(d.year_of_begin), buf, sizeof (int));
                buf += sizeof (int);

                printf("ID: %d\n", d.nusp);
                printf("NAME: %s\n", d.first_name);
                printf("LAST NAME: %s\n", d.last_name);
                printf("DEPARTAMENT: %s\n", d.department);
                printf("YEAR: %d\n", d.year_of_begin);
                printf("\n");

                close(arq);
                break;

            default:
                printf("Leaving....");
                break;
        }
    } while (cmd != 3);
    return 0;
}
```

So, my question is:
At `posix_memalign((void**)&buf, PAGE_SIZE, bufsize);`, am I allocating 158 bytes in a block memory of 4096 bytes (i.e., my page size), which means that I am wasting 3938 bytes? This happens since I have to write/read the aligned block memory, that in this case is 4096 (a power of two), right?

What happens if my PAGE_SIZE is equal to bufsize (consider that bufsize and PAGE_SIZE have sizes equal to 4096 bytes in this case)? Would this means that I am not wasting bytes in the memory and disk?

If I want to use the DIRECT_IO in Windows, is it possible? If yes, which library/function I have to use to allocate aligned block memories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be returned a block of memory that is guaranteed to be aligned to `PAGE_SIZE`; nothing more. Do not assume that there is 3938 bytes of space unused at the end - an intelligent allocator could easily have just given you the first entry in a slab of page aligned memory, and has kept the remainder for other 158 byte allocations.

You are wasting a large chunk of space on the disk by making use of only 158 bytes of a `PAGE_SIZE` chunk of disk, and in fact your write is actually putting undefined data into the disk for the block - everything from 158 - 4096 was never allocated to you, you should *not* be attempting to read from, or write to that memory.

If PAGE_SIZE == bufsize, then you're not wasting any disk space.

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971746/posix-o-direct-vs-windows-file-flag-write-through-file-flag-no-buffering), which explains how to obtain similar behaviour to the `O_DIRECT` flag.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understood the meaning of the posix_memalign. Now, when you said: "you should not be attempting to read from, or write to that memory.".. if I try to read/write only 158 bytes (as size) by using the read and write functions, it gives me errors. Then, because of this, I am using: write(arq, buf, PAGE_SIZE). Is it wrong? In my real application, the bufsize and PAGE_SIZE will be very similar in size.

Comment: You should not be attempting to read/write outside the bounds of the memory you allocated. If you need to read/write in 4K chunks, then you need to allocate in 4K chunks, even if your structure is smaller than 4K, and just accept the fact that the remainder of the memory/disk block is going to be garbage, and you're wasting both memory and disk space.