# POSIX way to do O_DIRECT?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, io, posix

Direct I/O is the most performant way to copy larger files, so I wanted to add that ability to a program.

Windows offers `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` and `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` in the Win32's [`CreateFileA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea). Linux, since 2.4.10, has the [O_DIRECT flag](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) for `open()`.

Is there a way to achieve the same result portably within POSIX? Like how the Win32 API here works from Windows XP to Windows 11, it would be nice to do direct IO across all UNIX-like systems in one reliably portable way.

Comment: If that was the case why would we need a Linux-specific flag?

Comment: @n.m. I was wondering if it was at all possible (even if in some roundabout way, without a simple open-based API).

Comment: Possibly duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971746/posix-o-direct-vs-windows-file-flag-write-through-file-flag-no-buffering

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no POSIX standard for direct IO.

There are at least two different APIs and behaviors that exist as of January 2023.  Linux, FreeBSD, and apparently IBM's AIX use an `O_DIRECT` flag to `open()`, while Oracle's Solaris uses a `directio()` function on an already-opened file descriptor.

The Linux use of the `O_DIRECT` flag to the [POSIX `open()` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/open.html) is documented on [the Linux `open()` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

> `O_DIRECT` (since Linux 2.4.10)
>
> Try to minimize cache effects of the I/O to and from thishttps://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html
> file.  In general this will degrade performance, but it is
> useful in special situations, such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QFSwhen applications do
> their own caching.  File I/O is done directly to/from
> user-space buffers.  The `O_DIRECT` flag on its own makes an
> effort to transfer data synchronously, but does not give
> the guarantees of the `O_SYNC` flag that data and necessary
> metadata are transferred.  To guarantee synchronous I/O,
> O_SYNC must be used in addition to `O_DIRECT`.  See NOTES
> below for further discussion.

Linux does not clearly specify how direct IO interacts with other descriptors open on the same file, or what happens when the file is mapped using `mmap()`; nor any alignment or size restrictions on direct IO read or write operations.  In my experience, these are all file-system specific and have been improving/becoming less restrictive over time, but most Linux filesystems require page-aligned IO buffers, and many (most? all?) (did?  still do?) require page-sized reads or writes.

FreeBSD follows the Linux model:  [passing an `O_DIRECT` flag to `open()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=open&sektion=2&manpath=freebsd-release-ports):

> `O_DIRECT` may be used to minimize or eliminate the cache effects
> of    reading and writing.  The system will attempt to avoid  caching the
> data you
> read or write.  If   it cannot avoid caching the data, it will minimize the
> impact the   data has on the cache.  Use of this flag can drastically reduce performance if not used with care.

OpenBSD does not support direct IO.  There's no mention of direct IO in either [the OpenBSD `open()`](https://man.openbsd.org/open) or [the OpenBSD 'fcntl()`](https://man.openbsd.org/fcntl) man pages.

IBM's AIX [appears to support a Linux-type `O_DIRECT` flag to `open()`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-scale/5.1.6?topic=applications-considerations-use-direct-io-o-direct), but actual published IBM AIX man pages don't seem to be generally available.

SGI's Irix also [supported the Linux-style `O_DIRECT` flag to `open()`](https://wiki.preterhuman.net/Direct_I/O_with_C%2B%2B_on_SGI_IRIX):

> `O_DIRECT`
>
> If set, all reads and writes on the resulting file descriptor will
> be performed directly to or from the user program buffer, provided
> appropriate size and alignment restrictions are met.  Refer to the
> `F_SETFL` and `F_DIOINFO` commands in the `fcntl(2)` manual entry for
> information about how to determine the alignment constraints.
> `O_DIRECT` is a Silicon Graphics extension and is only supported on
> local EFS and XFS file systems, and remote BDS file systems.

Of interest, the XFS file system on Linux originated with SGI's Irix.

Solaris uses a completely different interface.  Solaris uses a [specific `directio()` function to set direct IO on a per-file basis](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1465/directio-3c.html#scrolltoc):

> **Description**
>
> The `directio()` function provides advice to the system about the
> expected behavior of the application when accessing the data in the
> file associated with the open file descriptor `fildes`. The system
> uses this information to help optimize accesses to the file's data.
> The `directio()` function has no effect on the semantics of the other
> operations on the data, though it may affect the performance of other
> operations.
>
> The advice argument is kept per file; the last caller of `directio()`
> sets the advice for all applications using the file associated with
> `fildes`.
>
> Values for advice are defined in `<sys/fcntl.h>`.
>
> `DIRECTIO_OFF`
>
> Applications get the default system behavior when accessing file data.
>
> When an application reads data from a file, the data is first cached
> in system memory and then copied into the application's buffer (see
> `read(2)`). If the system detects that the application is reading
> sequentially from a file, the system will asynchronously "read ahead"
> from the file into system memory so the data is immediately available
> for the next `read(2)` operation.
>
> When an application writes data into a file, the data is first cached
> in system memory and is written to the device at a later time (see
> `write(2)`). When possible, the system increases the performance of
> `write(2)` operations by cacheing the data in memory pages. The data
> is copied into system memory and the `write(2)` operation returns
> immediately to the application. The data is later written
> asynchronously to the device. When possible, the cached data is
> "clustered" into large chunks and written to the device in a single
> write operation.
>
> The system behavior for `DIRECTIO_OFF` can change without notice.
>
> `DIRECTIO_ON`
>
> The system behaves as though the application is not going to reuse the
> file data in the near future. In other words, the file data is not
> cached in the system's memory pages.
>
> When possible, data is read or written directly between the
> application's memory and the device when the data is accessed with
> `read(2)` and `write(2)` operations. When such transfers are not
> possible, the system switches back to the default behavior, but just
> for that operation. In general, the transfer is possible when the
> application's buffer is aligned on a two-byte (short) boundary, the
> offset into the file is on a device sector boundary, and the size of
> the operation is a multiple of device sectors.
>
> This advisory is ignored while the file associated with `fildes` is
> mapped (see `mmap(2)`).
>
> The system behavior for `DIRECTIO_ON` can change without notice.

Notice also the behavior on Solaris is different:  if direct IO is enabled on a file by any process, *all* processes accessing that file will do so via direct IO (Solaris 10+ has no alignment or size restrictions on direct IO, so switching between direct IO and "normal" IO won't break anything.*).  And if a file is mapped via `mmap()`, direct IO on that file is disabled entirely.

* - That's not *quite* true - if you're using a [SAMFS or QFS filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QFS) in shared mode and access data from the filesystem's active metadata controller (where the filesystem must be mounted *by design* with the Solaris `forcedirectio` mount option so all access is done via direct IO on that one system in the cluster), if you disable direct IO for a file using `directio( fd, DIRECTIO_OFF )`, you **will** corrupt the filesystem.  Oracle's own top-end RAC database would do that if you did a database restore on the QFS metadata controller, and you'd wind up with a corrupt filesystem.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no.

IEEE 1003.1-2017 (the current POSIX standard afaik) doesn't mention any directives for direct I/O like `O_DIRECT`. That being said, a cursory glance tells me that GNU/Linux and FreeBSD support the `O_DIRECT` flag, while OpenBSD doesn't.

Beyond that, it appears that not all filesystems support `O_DIRECT` so even on a GNU/Linux system where you know your implementation of `open()` will recognize that directive, there's still no guarantee that you can use it.

At the end of the day, the only way I can see portable, direct I/O is runtime checks for whether or not the platform your program is running on supports it; you could do compile time checks, but I don't recommend it since filesystems can change, or your destination may not be on the OS drive. You might get super lucky and find a project out there that's already started to do this, but I kind of doubt it exists.

My recommendation for you is to start by writing your program to check for direct I/O support for your platform and act accordingly, adding checks and support for kernels and file systems you know your program will run on.

Wish I could be more help,

--K

Comment: Note that the level of support various Linux filesystems have for direct IO can vary.  Most will require page-aligned buffers, but IME some will only do full page-size reads/writes via direct IO, which makes reading or writing any file that's not a multiple of the system page size more complicated.