# NULL symbol in file using StreamWriter

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, stream

I want to add simple logger in to my app.
For this purpose I want to use `StreamWriter`.

Code:

```
private StreamWriter OutputStream;
OutputStream = new StreamWriter(this.LogFilePath, true);

// .... message - log from app

DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
message = string.Format("[{0:yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss}] {1}", now, message
if (OutputStream != null)
{
    OutputStream.WriteLine(message);
    OutputStream.Flush();
}
```

As result all strings are correctly captured and output is correct, but sometimes it can write empty string with invisible characters at the end:

sample:

> ```
>  [1970-08-31 14:56:26] Command response -> !c:65:f9:1b:82:97
> ```

and if i check this [with some tool that can show invisible characters](https://dostring.com/show-hidden-characters), I can see next:

[image]

As result ~600 lines of log - 125 mb.

I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10913690/2012219) that reason could be next:

> That happens. When you append a file first its size is corrected in
>   the directory (and that's transactional in NTFS) and then the actual
>   new data is written. There's good chance that if you shut down the
>   system you end up with a file appended with lots of null bytes because
>   data writes are not transactional unlike metadata (file size) writes.
>
> There's no absolute solution to this problem.

Also tried to

check characters with `isControl` other similar checks;

tried to `Trim` last characters;

checked [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file) - looks like all correct

Any advice?

Comment: How are you _reading_ the file?

Comment: I don't, just write, appending new line `OutputStream.WriteLine`

Comment: No, you must do. How else do you know the file contains null characters, if you don't read the file?

Comment: I downloaded it from mobile device and open local on pc via `glogg`. For writing I guess i shouldn't read it because `new StreamWriter(this.LogFilePath, true);` - append file and `OutputStream.WriteLine` simple append stream (if i understood correctly from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.writeline?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Do you shutdown the system or the applicarion while the file is written to? Also where does it happen, iOS, Android or windows or all three? And what has it to do with unity3d?

Comment: @Ackdari, No system is running, as soon as it shutdown i close the steam; It's happened  on Android device. unity is because app created within unity  IDE (some kind of 3d stuff inside app )

Comment: I would read the file with code as well (e.g. `File.ReadAllText`), to ensure that the null characters are not added in during the transfer of the file from the mobile device to your PC, or some bug somewhere else.

Comment: @Sweeper i guess file transfer it's not a reason, because this null chars are completely takes random place in file - at the end of diff lines...

Comment: @gbk what is your unity version?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8  2019 lts

Comment: @gbk Do you call dispose method?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 Yep, on destroy callback, also tried to change code with ‘using’ keyword

Comment: Looks like this symbols are randomly appended to file time to time... maybe i miss something or it depends on logged message - you can see that date is 1970 instead of correct one, but ‘DateTime.Now’ used with custom formatting...

Comment: What is your build platform?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 Builds on macOs hSierra for android

Comment: Scripting backends?

Comment: I attached this script to game object shared between scenes, script contains only few lines of code related to capturing logs; thats it... not sure if i correctly got last question @0xBFE1A8

Comment: @gdk [Scripting backend](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/windowsstore-scriptingbackends.html).

Comment: Ah, sorry @0xBFE1A8 .Net

Comment: Try changing your scripting backend to il2cpp

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 I tested your advice and nothing helps.. but i update a bit logic and now looks like it's create log file with correct size - please check my answer for ref, and thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

In case someone faced with same issue - reason for me unknown and i may only guess.... but I rewrite logic with log system and bug disappear:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;

public class EventLogger : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string logFileName = "btlog.txt";
    public bool EchoToConsole = true;
    public bool AddTimeStamp = true;
    public bool EnableFileStorage = true;

    private string LogFilePath
    {
        get
        {
            return Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, logFileName);
        }
    }

    private static EventLogger Singleton = null;
    const string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff";

    public static EventLogger Instance
    {
        get { return Singleton; }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        if (Singleton != null)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Multiple EventLogger Singletons exist!");
            return;
        }

        Singleton = this;

        if (this.EnableFileStorage)
        {
            if (File.Exists(LogFilePath))
            {
                long length = new FileInfo(LogFilePath).Length;
                int limit = 1024 * 1024 * 5; // 5mb
                if (length > limit)
                {
                    File.Delete(LogFilePath);
                    Log("log file removed");
                }
            }

            Log("-------------------");
            Log("NEW SESSION STARTED");
        }
    }

    private async Task Write(string message)
    {
        if (this.EnableFileStorage)
        {
            if (AddTimeStamp)
            {
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

                string strDate = now.ToString(format);
                string trimmed = new string(message.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray());
                message = string.Format("[{0}] {1}", strDate, trimmed);
            }

            using (StreamWriter outputStream = new StreamWriter(this.LogFilePath, true))
            {
                await outputStream.WriteLineAsync(message);
            }

            if (EchoToConsole)
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log(message);
            }
        }
    }

    [Conditional("DEBUG"), Conditional("PROFILE")]
    public static void Log(string Message)
    {
        if (EventLogger.Instance != null)
        {
            _ = EventLogger.Instance.Write(Message);
        }
        else
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(Message);
        }
    }
}
```